# Test method refuses to execute parts of trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, failing-tests, before-trigger

I have this **beforeUpdate** trigger on Lead, which is calls a static method to populate 3 different fields based on data passed to a Picklist field.

Field definitions:

- **Campus__c:** Picklist
- **Secondary_Campus__c:** Lookup to a custom object named Campus
- **Tertiary_Campus__c:** Lookup to a custom object named Campus
- **Quaternary_Campus__c:** Lookup to a custom object named Campus

How the logic is supposed to work is:

1. Web-forms / Marketo sends in a 3 letter campus code via the Campus__c picklist field.
2. This method checks whether old and new values of Campus__c field are same or not and if not same, step 3.
3. Check the fields secondary_campus__c, tertiary_campus__c etc. in order to see whichever is empty/null and populate it with the matching Campus ID from the Campus object.

**Note:** There is also a field called Primary_campus__c which gets populated in a similar manner during the beforeInsert cycle

**Trigger: Linked method**

```
public static void addMultipleCampuses( List<Lead> newLeads, List<Lead> oldLeads ) {

    map<String,Campus__c> mapCampusData = CommLib.getCampusMap();

// Update
if( TriggerMonitor.runOnce() ) {        

    // Checks for changes in lead data
    for( Integer i = 0; i < newLeads.size(); i++ ) {

        // If Campus__c doesn't match
        if( oldLeads[i].Campus__c != NULL && 
            newLeads[i].Campus__c != NULL &&
            newLeads[i].Campus__c != oldLeads[i].Campus__c ) {

            if( newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c == NULL && 
                newLeads[i].Tertiary_Campus__c == NULL &&
                newLeads[i].Quaternary_Campus__c == NULL ) { 
                // Fill Secondary Campus
                newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c = mapCampusData.get( newLeads[i].Campus__c ).Id;
                continue;
            } // sec campus == null?

            if( newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c != NULL && 
                newLeads[i].Tertiary_Campus__c == NULL &&
                newLeads[i].Quaternary_Campus__c == NULL ) {
                // Fill Tertiary Campus
                newLeads[i].Tertiary_Campus__c = mapCampusData.get( newLeads[i].Campus__c ).Id;
                continue;
            } // ter campus == null?

            if( newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c != NULL && 
                newLeads[i].Tertiary_Campus__c != NULL &&
                newLeads[i].Quaternary_Campus__c == NULL ) {
                // Fill Quaternary Campus
                newLeads[i].Quaternary_Campus__c = mapCampusData.get( newLeads[i].Campus__c ).Id;
            } // quat campus == null?

        } // if

        i++;

    } // for

    } // TriggerMonitor.runOnce()

}
```

**Test Method**

```
static testMethod void testMultipleCampusAssignments() {  

    // Start Test
    test.startTest();

try {

    Lead leadA = new Lead();
    leadA.FirstName = 'Multi Campus';
    leadA.LastName = 'Test Ting';
    leadA.Email = 'test@gmail.com';
    leadA.Phone = '1234567890';
    leadA.Country = 'United Kingdom';
    leadA.Status = 'New';
    leadA.LeadSource = 'Direct Mail';

    // Specify Campus
    leadA.Campus__c = 'CHI';

    // =============
    System.debug( '==== Inserting Lead with CHI ====' );
    insert leadA;

    ID leadId = leadA.ID;

    // First Test - Primary Campus
    leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Primary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
    System.assertEquals( leadA.Campus__c, leadA.Primary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c );

    // Update Campus
    leadA.Campus__c = 'SFO';
    update leadA;
    leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
    System.assertEquals( 'SFO', leadA.Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c );

    // Update Campus
    leadA.Campus__c = 'NASH';
    update leadA;
    leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Tertiary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
    System.assertEquals( 'NASH', leadA.Tertiary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c );

    // Update Campus
    leadA.Campus__c = 'MIA';         
    update leadA;
    leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Quaternary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
    System.assertEquals( 'MIA', leadA.Quaternary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c );            

}
catch( Exception e ) {
    System.debug( e.getMessage() );
}         

    // Stop Test
    test.stopTest();

}
```

No matter whatever I try, the test fails at the 2nd System.assert() onwards and highlights the 3 conditional blocks in the method as not covered.
[image]

Can anyone please point out why the test keeps failing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding debugging to see what values are in `Campus__c `, `Secondary_Campus__c`, `Tertiary_Campus__c` and `Quaternary_Campus__c`? You may also want to check the value of `i` as well in your `for loop`

Comment: Check the values of your campus lookup fields after insert.  It looks like those fields may get populated on insert.  If so, then none of your inner if statements would result with true.

Comment: Printing out the error in the catch block of your test is poor practice. If your trigger throws an error your test would still pass.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions.

I put System.debug after the insert and didn't find the 3 fields populated. They didn't even get returned in the result set - so am assuming they haven't been populated.

Comment: Putting the debug statements directly in the trigger will help you figure out what all the variables are set to when the trigger executes.

Comment: **Never put your whole test in a try catch block!** It cannot fail and is therefore useless and very difficult to understand the results.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: so which part should go in try catch? Just DB operations?

Comment: In a test method like you have, there should be no need for a try-catch at all. In fact, your `test.startTest` shouldn't occur until after or just before you insert your lead. Before if your trigger fires after insert. After if it doesn't fire until after update.

Comment: Yeah no try catch at all. It should fail not silently but **loudly**!

Answer (score 1):

This was too much to put in a comment. In your test code here, where your problems begin:

```
// Update Campus
    leadA.Campus__c = 'SFO';
    update leadA;
    leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
    System.assertEquals( 'SFO', leadA.Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c );
```

It would seem that your query and asserts should look like:

```
leadA = [SELECT Id, Campus__c, Primary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c, Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
System.assertEquals( 'SFO', leadA.Primary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c);
System.assertEquals( 'CHI', leadA.Secondary_Campus__r.Shortcode__c);
```

With the update, you've presumably changed the primary campus to 'SFO' and the previous primary campus is now the secondary campus.

**Edit** in response to comments:

Your code says:

```
newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c = mapCampusData.get( newLeads[i].Campus__c ).Id;
```

I'm not certain what mapCampusData is, but it doesn't appear to be assigning the old value of `Campus__c` to `Secondary_Campus__c` for the lead as something like the below would, assuming `oldLeadsmap` is the equivalent of `trigger.Oldmap`.

```
newLeads[i].Secondary_Campus__c = oldLeadsmap.get(newLeads[i].Id).Campus__c
```

You'd then still need another statement which assigns the value to your custom object. The above only assigns the value to your custom field on the lead. Unless one is a look-up to the other, you'd need to do both. Perhaps that's what your mapCampusData does? If so, perhaps your statement above isn't correct? Perhaps you don't need the `.ID` at the end of the statement?

Comment: Hi, perhaps my explanation wasn't clear enough. Here's how the flow happens: 1. On INSERT, the value in Campus__c get's translated to the ID of the Campus relational object and Primary_campus__c is populated with it. 2. On every subsequent UPDATES, 2nd, 3rd and 4th campus fields get populated in a similar manner, as long as they're blank. 

thanks.

Comment: First, @adrianlarson is correct, you don't need a try-catch block for any of your test. See my edited response above.